# why we say in a sea of multiculturalism

Tags: grammar, word-usage

the question is about definite and indefinite. 
why do we say in a sea of multiculturalism rather than in the sea of multiculturalism. cause i think it is multiculturalism not any other things so it is definite. can anybody help to answer this question.

Comment: No capital letters. No question marks. No apostrophes. No research. No effort. No bother.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase appears to be indefinite, as "a sea of multiculturalism" is not unique, and exists in other than just the specified place to which it refers.

"the sea of multiculturalism" implies one of the following:

- that it is unique and no others exist, or it is being compared only to other areas that are not diverse.
- that this metaphor was specified previously in context.
- that although there may exist many seas of multiculturalism, this is the one to which all others are compared. (Generally reflects an opinion.) Often in this case emphasis would be placed on "the".

Context is important.

Comment: +1 But I am not sure I believe any of it! I have never thought about the phrase until now. The fact is that it is odd to say "lost in a sea of multiculturalism", but it never struck me before. I rarely use the phrase, because I am never happy with the baggage it carries.

Comment: I think of multiculturalism is used to decorate sea , so in my opinion it is definite. it is not a/the sea of for example entertainment but sea of multiculturalism.